# How to set dat to the View from 2D Array type Api in SwiftUI?

Tags: json, swift, multidimensional-array, swiftui, struct

I have 2D type Array data in Json File And wants to fetch the data in View Model And I tried many Time and unable to fetch the data I used the Model  which generated from the [QuickType.io](https://app.quicktype.io/) And I use the MVVM pattern for fetching the data.

This is My Json Data.

```
{ "publisherPlans": [[ "Name", "Free","Prime" ],["Book Sell",9999,9999],["Book Bulk Sell",0,9999],["Magazine start-up",9999,9999],["Demo book request count for School",5,9999],["Demo book request Acception",9999,9999],["Assign book for demo",25,9999]]}
```

And this is My Model which generated By website

```
public struct SchoolPlanModel: Decodable {
    public let publisherPlans: [[PublisherPlan]]

}

public enum PublisherPlan:Decodable {
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)
}
```

And this is My ViewModel here I am trying to fetch data from Json file

```
class ReadData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var datas = [String]()
    
    func getData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "********api/plans") else { return }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            Task{@MainActor in
                let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(SchoolPlanModel.self, from: data).publisherPlans
  print(results)
            }
        } catch {
            print("---> error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

This My View Here I want to show Data.

```
struct SchoolPlanView: View{
    @StateObject var list = ReadData()
    
    var body: some View{
        ForEach(list.datas,id: \.self) { array in
                HStack{
                    ForEach(array.utf8CString, id: \.self) { element in
                        Text("\(element)")
                  }
                }
              }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the json you received is poorly designed so you end up with a strange model in my opinion which is hard to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this approach, works for me. I had to modify a few things in your code, but should be straightforward to understand. Let me know if you need more explanations.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SchoolPlanView()
    }
}

struct SchoolPlanModel: Decodable {
    var publisherPlans: [[PublisherPlan]]
}

enum PublisherPlan: Decodable, Hashable {
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)

    // -- here 
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .integer(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(PublisherPlan.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for Plan"))
    }
}

class ReadData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var datas: [[PublisherPlan]] = []  // <-- here
    
    func getData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://myexampleurl.com") else { return }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            Task{@MainActor in
                let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(SchoolPlanModel.self, from: data)
                self.datas = results.publisherPlans // <-- here
            }
        } catch {
            print("---> error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

struct SchoolPlanView: View{
    @StateObject var list = ReadData()
    
    var body: some View {
        // -- here
        List(list.datas, id: \.self) { array in
            HStack{
                ForEach(array, id: \.self) { item in
                    switch item {
                       case .integer(let int): Text("\(int)")
                       case .string(let str): Text(str)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await list.getData()  // <-- here
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

To get the headings for columns, try this approach, where
you separate the data and headings at the source, in `getData()`.
You will have to adjust the display using columns etc...

```
class ReadData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var datas: [[PublisherPlan]] = []
    @Published var headings: [String] = []  // <-- here
    
    func getData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://myexampleurl.com/plans") else { return }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            //       print("\n \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject) \n")
            Task{@MainActor in
                let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(SchoolPlanModel.self, from: data)
                // the data minus the first array of headings
                datas = Array(results.publisherPlans.dropFirst()) // <-- here
                // get the headings
                if let headers = results.publisherPlans.first { // <-- here
                    for h in headers {
                        switch h {
                           case .integer(_): break
                           case .string(let str): self.headings.append(str)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("---> error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

struct SchoolPlanView: View{
    @StateObject var list = ReadData()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(list.headings, id: \.self) { heading in  // <-- here
                    Text(heading)
                }
            }
            List(list.datas, id: \.self) { array in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(array, id: \.self) { item in
                        switch item {
                        case .integer(let int): Text("\(int)")
                        case .string(let str): Text(str)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await list.getData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works also for me. @workingdog I want to set the ```Name, Free,Prime``` as heading of column how I set?

Comment: updated my answer with a possible solution, to get the headings for eventual columns.